# How can I take data from a flow meter and use it in my python code?

Tags: python, file-io, serial-communication

I have created a program that connects to a dispensing pump, sets psi, sets dispensing time and time between dispenses for various dispensing pressures. Using this code I want to be able to calibrate a flow sensor that is typically used with water. To do this I have to find flow in mL/s. I have all the information I need to calculate the actual flow rate (I can convert from mg to mL with information I already have, and I will use a user input to get mass) but I would like to be able to read the measured flow rate from the flow sensor into the program and find the median. With this information I will output the measured flow rate and the actual flow rate into a table to be input into some calibration software. The issue I am having is figuring out how to import the data that the flow meter is measuring into Python.

tl;dr: I want to capture a flow rate over time from a flow sensor, and calculate the median of the required flow rate in my Python code, then output to a text file.

I would definitely consider myself a beginner at Python and other coding, and I would really appreciate any insights people may have!

Below I added the code I am using to try to achieve this, the issue I am having is understanding how to get the flow into the code. I am using a CorSolutions Eco flow meter.

```
    # define a list to fill with measured flow rates
    measured = []
    # create loop to fill list of measured flow rate
    for j in range(dispensingTime):
        # save most recent flow rate
        flow = however i get this info from the flow meter
        # append flow to the end of the measured list
        measured.append(flow)
```

Comment: this will receive better feedback if you provide some code that you already have with pointers to the spots that need improvement

Comment: `I want to capture a flow rate over time from a flow sensor` that's pretty broad and most likely depends on the hardware. It isn't clear what you are asking. Are you having problems with code you wrote? Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. This isn't a discussion forum

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I added the code in and hardware information. I'll keep what you said in mind if I ever post on SO again.